# Different product layout based on product

Tags: magento2, product, layout, magento2.2

**What I have tried so far**

As the title describes. How can one implement different layouts per product based on a value on that product (in this case a custom EAV on the Product entity)

At first I thought I'd create a custom product type for these type of products. This would work fine. Although you cannot change the product types for existing products.

Then I thought I could make a new page layout, though you can not add content to the product layout.

Lastly I thought I would simply add all these products in a category and change the product view there (via Design > Layout update XML) but this would involve the end user writing XML which is something I'd like to avoid if possible. Same goes for changing the Design > Layout update XML for each product.

**Other info:**

I have create a Magento module which should replace the product image with a different view. Currently I have overwritten (in my module) the view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml with my custom content (removing the original image/video blocks and adding my own blocks) this works fine though ALL products now have the new layout.

All products are simple products currently

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can  achieve this thing by writing small code

What you need to do is add layout via event `layout_load_before`, you can use this event to add your dynamic layout.

Here is sample code for you, please modify as per your need

what you can do is create `events.xml` in your module

`[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- for diffrentiate layout.xml on product basis -->
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="load_custom_handler" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

In your `[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore.php` file write below code

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    private $registry;

    public function __construct(
       ............
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       ............
    ) {
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

        if (!$product) {
          return $this;
        }
        if ($product->getMyvalue()) { // your condition
           $layout = $observer->getLayout();
           $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('your_handle_name');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And now go to `[Vendor]\[Module]\view\frontend\layout\your_handle_name.xml` file and write your code.

This file only added to your specific condition of product

Comment: What's this line stands for ? `$layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('your_handler_name');` , I dont understand handler, I also R & D for layout handler, Resources doesn't make me understood. If you can help me out OR some useful links.

Comment: @Vivek that line add layout and its find `your_handler_name.xml` file in all modules

Comment: Hi, Here all thing work fine, Even my observer also get called. But my custom handler is not render, It render only catalog_product_view.xml, Please let me know if anything I miss. I have created catalog_product_view_extension.xml

Comment: @Ravi , please check your handler path and name , or other wise ask new question and put your code over there and send me link of that question I will check

Comment: @Ravi , `your_handler_name` would be custom name any name you can give here, just create a file with that name

Comment: I'll create a new Question. Give me just min. Thanks a lot for Response.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232659/magento2-how-to-set-product-wise-different-layout

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using xml for bulk products. for that you will have to override helper and create attribute for that. let me explain you descriptively.

> Step 1: Create product attribute '**customlayout**'.

- Create cutom product-attribute for custom layout, here I have just
  created attribute '***customlayout***' with type **boolean(yes/no)**.
- Assign this attribute in appropriate attribute-set.
- Now '**customlayout**' is visible in products , set **yes** in those products which you want to set different layout.

[image]

> Step 2: Override Helper function initProductLayout().

Override above helper function in your custom module and also change in **di.xml** file to override helper.

**app/code/YourCompany/YourModule/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View" type="YourCompany\YourModule\Helper\Product\View" />
</config>
```

in **YourCompany\YourModule\Helper\Product\view.php** file.

```
public function initProductLayout(ResultPage $resultPage, $product, $params = null)
    {
      ......
      // add handle params
      ......
    if ($params && $params->getBeforeHandles()) {
        foreach ($params->getBeforeHandles() as $handle) {
            $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['customlayout' => $product->getCustomlayout(), 'id' => $product->getId(), 'sku' => $urlSafeSku], $handle);
            $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $product->getTypeId()], $handle, false);
        }
    }

    $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['customlayout' => $product->getCustomlayout(), 'id' => $product->getId(), 'sku' => $urlSafeSku]);
    $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $product->getTypeId()], null, false);

    if ($params && $params->getAfterHandles()) {
        foreach ($params->getAfterHandles() as $handle) {
            $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['customlayout' => $product->getCustomlayout(), 'id' => $product->getId(), 'sku' => $urlSafeSku], $handle);
            $resultPage->addPageLayoutHandles(['type' => $product->getTypeId()], $handle, false);
        }
    }

   ........

    }
```

Here I have added custom attribute for custom layout handle.
now you can create custom layout file to use this attribute.
let's create custom handle file.

> Step 3: Create layout file for custom layout.

Create layout file in your custom theme/ custom module.
**`catalog_product_view_customlayout_1.xml`**

Here you can set your custom changes in it. it will be applied to all the products which have '**customlayout**' attibute value is '**yes**'.

Comment: @tuim , please follow above steps, it will work for you. above steps are working for me .

Comment: @tuim, Have you tried our solution.? Is this work for you.?

Comment: Hi, I've decided to go with the solution below. Since I didn't want to override the complete initProductLayout function with a custom implementation. That would decrease maintainability.