# Magento2: How to set product wise different layout

Tags: magento2, product, layout, custom-theme

I have Two product. Both are Downloadable.
I want different layout for both product.

Except below concept:

```
catalog_product_view_id_1.xml
```

The second concept I am using is with help of observer, But also this one is not working.
Below are my code. Please see and let me know if any change.

Path: etc/event.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="layout_load_before">
    <observer name="catalog_product_view_extension" instance="Custom\Extensionlayout\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
</event>
</config>
```

Path: Observer/LayoutLoadBefore.php

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Extensionlayout\Observer;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
 */
protected $_registry;

public function __construct(
   \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
)
{
    $this->_registry = $registry;
}


public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');


    //echo ; die;

    if (!$product){
      return $this;
    }
    if($product->getName() == 'book2'){ // your condition


       $layout = $observer->getLayout();
       $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_product_view_extension');
    }

    return $this;
}
}
```

And here is my custom layout path:
view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_extension.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.overview" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.price.final" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.price.tier" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.additional" remove="true"/>
    </body>
    </page>
```

Here what happens, Observer is getting called but my custom handler not rendered.
Anyone did this kind of change.
Please suggest.

Comment: Change in name `catalog_product_view_**` to other like `my_downlodable_view` and try

Comment: Thanks, It gets called, But again this handler reflects on other products too. see my condition also if($product->getName() == 'book2'){
            $layout = $observer->getLayout();
           $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('my_downlodable_view');
        }else{
            $layout = $observer->getLayout();
           $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('catalog_product_view');
        }

Comment: please check why Your condition always becomes true

Comment: I have checked my condition for both products. Conditions are working fine. But all time this handler call: catalog_product_view, let me check

Comment: remove else part of your code `catalog_product_view` will call in all condition

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, It's done. I have created new attribute Yes/No and the help of this. It achieves. Thanks again.

Comment: You are always welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can  achieve this thing by writing small code

What you can do is add add layout via event `layout_load_before`, you can use this event to add your dynamic layout.

Here is sample code for you, please modify as per your need

what you can do is create `events.xml` in your module

`[Vendor]/[Module]/etc/frontend/events.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!-- for diffrentiate layout.xml on product basis -->
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="load_custom_handler" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore" />
    </event>
</config>
```

In your `[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\LayoutLoadBefore.php` file write below code

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

class LayoutLoadBefore implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry;

    public function __construct(
       ............
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       ............
    ){
        $this->registry = $registry;
    }


    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $this->registry->registry('current_product');

        if (!$product) {
          return $this;
        }
        if ($product->getMyvalue()) { // your condition
           $layout = $observer->getLayout();
           $productId = $product->getId(); 
           $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle("my_downlodable_view_id_$productId");
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And now go to `[Vendor]\[Module]\view\frontend\layout\my_downlodable_view_id_yourProductId.xml` file and write your code.

This file only added to your specific condition of product

Answer (score 0):

Create new layout file inside your theme scope

The name of layout file will be:

**catalog_product_view_id_number** and we’ll place it in:

```
app/design/frontend/VendorName/ThemeName/Namespace_Module/layout/catalog_product_view_id_number.xml
```